# Entity Framework and foreign key relationships producing slow sql performance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-5

I have normalized a Country/region/city database into multiple tables. City has a foreign key to region which has a foreign key to country.

The `CITY` table includes 2 additional columns for finding the associated numerical `IPAddress`. As you can imagine the city table has over 4 million records (representing the cities in the world which maps back to a region and then a country).

`CITY`, `REGION`, `COUNTRY` are entities that I have mapped with Entity Framework power tools, that all have a name column (that represents a `cityname`, `regionname`, `countryname`, respectively), and a primary key IDENTITY column that is indexed.

Let's say I have a table / entity called `VisitorHit` that has the following columns:

```
id as int (primary key, identity)
dateVisited as datetime 
FK_City as int (which has a many to one relationship to the CITY entity)
```

In code I use the `VisitorHit` entity like:

```
var specialVisitors = VisitorRepository.GetAllSpecialVisitors();
var distinctCountries = specialVisitors.Select(i => i.City.CityName).Distinct().ToArray();
```

now the `GetAllSpecialVisitors` returns a subset of the actual visitors (and it works pretty fast). The typical subset contains approximately 10,000 rows. The `Select Distinct` statement takes minutes to return. Ultimately I need to further delimit the `distinctCountries` by a date range (using the `visitorhit.datevisited` field) and return the count for each `distinctCountry`.

Any ideas on how I could speed up this operation?

Comment: Have the foreign key columns been properly indexed? Have you looked at the execution plans of the queries to see any potential bottlenecks?

Comment: Although I've suggested an answer below, it might also be useful to update your question with the code for `VisitorRepository.GetAllSpecialVisitors();`

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at SQL Profiler to see what SQL is being generated for this. My first guess (since you don't post the code for `GetAllSpecialVisitors`) would be that you are lazy loading the City rows in which case you are going to be producing multiple calls to the database (one for each instance in `specialVisitors`) to get the city. You can eager load the city in the call to `GetAllSpecialVisistors()`.

Use `.Include("City")` or `.Include(v=>v.City)`

e.g. Something like this:

```
var result = from hit in context.VisitorHits
             where /* predicates */
             .Include(h =>h.City)
```

Like I said, you need to look at what the SQL Profiler is showing you to see what SQL Is actually being sent to the SQL Server. But when I have issues like this it turns out to be the most common cause.

If you try writing the query yourself in the SSMS and it works well then another solution may be to write a view and query on the view. That is something else I've done on occasion when Entity Framework produces unwieldy queries that don't work efficiently.